# Highlight the entire row if there is no data in a Single Column in jqxgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

My Requirement is :

I need to Highlight the entire Row if there is no data in atleast single column in jqx grid can any one Help me out ?

```
var cellsrenderer = function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties, rowdata) 
{    
 if (value > 2) 
 {
   return '<span style="margin: 4px; float: ' + columnproperties.cellsalign + '; color: #ff0000;font-weight:bold;">' + value + '</span>';
 }    
 else 
 {
    return '<span style="margin: 4px; float: ' + columnproperties.cellsalign + '; color: #00000;font-weight:normal;">' + value + '</span>';
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that: [Cells Styling](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/gridcellclass.htm?arctic). The sample shows conditional cells formatting. In your case you have to implement the "cellclassname" function for all Grid columns. By doing that you will be able to implement conditional Row formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the `cellclassname` route, you can try something like this:

```
var cellClass = function(gridId, highlightClass) {
    highlightClass = highlightClass || 'default';
    return function(row, columnfield, value) {
        return hasEmptyCell(gridId, row) ? highlightClass : '';
        // where hasEmptyCell is a function that checks if a row has an empty cell
    };
};

var cols = [
    { text: 'Product Name', datafield: 'ProductName', width: 250 },
    { text: 'Quantity per Unit', datafield: 'QuantityPerUnit', cellsalign: 'right', align: 'right', width: 120 },
    { text: 'Unit Price', datafield: 'UnitPrice', align: 'right', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2', width: 100 },
    { text: 'Units In Stock', datafield: 'UnitsInStock', cellsalign: 'right', width: 100 },
    { text: 'Discontinued', columntype: 'checkbox', datafield: 'Discontinued' },
];

for (var i in cols) {
    cols[i].cellclassname = cellClass('#test-grid', 'highlighted');
}

// then initialize jqxGrid using cols
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
    columns: cols
    /* ... other properties */
});
```